# How can I choose the value of camel:process ref based on the field in incoming file?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a camel route to process incoming files. Here's how it looks like so far:

```
<camel:route id="myResultsFileRoute">
    <camel:from uri="ref:myResultsFileEndpoint"/>
    <camel:process ref="myResultsFileProcessor"/> 
    <camel:to uri="direct:myResultsCommonRoute"/>
    <camel:onException>
        <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
        <camel:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="5" redeliveryDelay="30000"/>
    </camel:onException>
</camel:route>
```

As you can see above, I'm using `myResultsFileProcessor`. I have a bean like this defined below:

```
<bean id="myResultsFileProcessor"
      class="com.mypackage.processes.file.host.myResults.MyResultsFileInitialProcessor">
    <constructor-arg name="myResultToEventAssembler" ref="myResultToEventAssembler"/>
    <constructor-arg name="myResultsNamespace" value="$res{schema.uri.myResults}"/>
</bean>
```

Incoming xml file has one node in it that describe its type. Until now, no matter what type it was, I was always using `myResultsFileProcessor`, however now after I introduced another type of the incoming file, I need to introduce new File Processor for it. So I created the new bean:

```
<bean id="myOtherResultsFileProcessor"
      class="com.mypackage.processes.file.host.myResults.MyOtherFileInitialProcessor">
    <constructor-arg name="myResultToEventAssembler" ref="myOtherResultToEventAssembler"/>
    <constructor-arg name="myResultsNamespace" value="$res{schema.uri.myResults}"/>
</bean>
```

Can you tell me how can I modify my camel route so that - based on the field in the file, it chooses either `myResultsFileProcessor` or `myOtherResultsFileProcessor`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use choice EIP https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/choice-eip.html

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <xpath>/node/type = 'file_type'</xpath>
        <process ref="myResultsFileProcessor"/> 
    </when>
    <when>
        <xpath>/node/type = 'other_file_type'</xpath>
        <process ref="myOtherResultsFileProcessor"/> 
    </when>
</choice>
```